# MSSQL Query returns unknown data type in a CONVERT date field

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query like this

```
SELECT field1, field2, CONVERT(date, field3) as fieldDate FROM table
```

Pretty simple indeed, It's works on the server and another mac, but, in my mac, PHP returns the message:

> **Severity: Warning
>   Message: mssql_query(): column 3 has unknown data type (40)**

Te query object returned only have the field1 and field2

I'm using PHP Version `5.5.34` with freetds and `mssql.so` installed in my mac.
The SQL Server is in the cloud, and as a I said, it's works fine in another mac and the server where the code is running, but in my development Mac doesn´t

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT field1, field2, date(field3) as fieldDate FROM table
```

Comment: you sure there is a `date()` function in `SQL Server` ?

Comment: What version of SQL server @Mech

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAST()

```
select field1, field2, cast(field3 as date) as fieldDate FROM table
```