# SQL Server query returns unknown data type after I CONVERT XML content

Tags: php, sql-server, xml

Here is my query which was working for months:

```
SELECT description,
CAST(REPLACE( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), LogContent), '&', '&amp;' ) as XML)
- and the rest of the query -
```

It was reading a string from the database and converting it to XML, which I was then displaying in an HTML page. It was working beautifully up until a couple of weeks back.

The data has not changed in the database, but there may have been a software upgrade (possibly PHP) which I am not aware of.

Now the same query returns the correct response for Column 1, but for my XML I get:

```
PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): column 2 has unknown data type (241)
```

I haven't been able to find anything useful on this one. Did anyone encounter it?

(*[MSSQL Query returns unknown data type in a CONVERT date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470451/mssql-query-returns-unknown-data-type-in-a-convert-date-field#_=_)* seems similar, but dropping the convert in place of casts has not helped me here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to find an alternative library to connect to SQL Server if this is actually the bug in `ext/mssql` reported way back in 2014 which status is now won't fix, quoted from [PHP bug-tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68228):

> **[2016-10-15 23:19 UTC] kalle@php.net:**
>
> *With MSSQL being removed from PHP as of PHP7.0, and ext/mssql not having a maintainer, I'm gonna close this report as a Won't fix, until maybe one day it will find a new maintainer.*
>
> *Alternatively you can use `sqlsrv` from Microsoft if you are on Windows, or `pdo_dblib` if you are on Unix.*

Or you might try to rollback your system from the breaking upgrade.